# Example iphone audio streaming app

Tags: iphone

Is there an example application (open source or pay) for iphone that streams audio from the internet?  Something like Pandora... bonus points if it allows for background audio playing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm how about Pandora :). The Apress book "[iPhone Cool Projects](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430223573)" has a chapter on the Pandora app and how it was written. Here is the URL to see the book details page which has the source code for free on the left menu. Hope this helps!

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430223573

*this book was written before background audio was available so this will give you tons of data to get started but you will have to add your own code for background audio capabilities. Matt Gallagher has written a few excellent articles on the topic as well that will get you up and running quickly as well. His most recent article can be fond here:

[Streaming MP3/AAC audio again](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html)